# S#arp Architecture Template

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, s#arp-architecture

I am having a VS problem with S#arp Architecture; the template does not appear in the new -> project; what I can do?

I've tried already registering the installvstemplates and the setup command in the VS prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the advice guys, reistalled VS and it worked perfectly, seems it was a install bug or something.